# SharePoint List/Excel to Ms Access splitting at delimiter

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I have a SharePoint list, employees go in and fill in information, then I export the list to Excel (in my company, Access and SharePoint don't play well with each other) and import it into Access to run reports. It's great, except for one column. Employees can work in multiple counties, so on SharePoint I have a look up column where they can select multiple counties...the problem is, when I export it to Excel it looks like this:

[County] Outagamie;#1

[County] Ashland;#35;#Bayfield;#66;#Douglas;#67;#Iron;#68

I only want the county names:

[County] Outagamie

[County] Ashland, Bayfield, Douglas, Iron

Again some employees may have one county, some could have 5 or 6. I know I can do a formula in excel, but I'm trying to make this easy on other people who will run this report, so I would like to just import the Excel file and run the reports based on queries.

For the love of God, you would think this would be an easy thing in an Access query, but when I research this, I only find ways to do it in Excel. There has to be a way to do it in Access.  Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

Hummm, seems like Find/Replace would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I try the Find/Replace it says no items can be found, did a copy and paste of the text, but it still doesn't come up with any results. I searched Google for the replace function, but I haven't found any good information for multiple criteria. At least in Access...I'm trying to skip using Excel, but it seems that might be my only choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small helper function like this:

```
Public Function CleanString(ByVal Value As String) As String

    Dim Parts   As Variant
    Dim Part    As Integer
    Dim Result  As String

    Parts = Split(Value, ";#")
    For Part = LBound(Parts) To UBound(Parts)
        If Part Mod 2 = 0 Then
            If Result <> "" Then
                Result = Result & ", "
            End If
            Result = Result & Parts(Part)
        End If
    Next

    CleanString = Result

End Function
```